# Required a bean of type that could not be found Spring Boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Spring Boot application fails to start?

[Here is my Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5wwK.png)

Below is my main class.

```
package com.example;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Start {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Start.class, args);
        }
    }
```

And my console is

```
2017-11-28 11:48:52.187  WARN 7316 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Description:

Field userRepository in com.example.controller.UserController required a bean of type 'com.example.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

Application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=example
```

UserRepository interface

```
package com.example.repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import com.example.model.User;

public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>{
    public User findOneByName(String name);
}
```

Here is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user/")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    public UserRepository userRepository;
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void create(@RequestBody User user){
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can be many reasons. Please provide more configurational details as there could be numerous reasons for the `UserRepository` not to be mapped.

Comment: I have added more details in console section. plz check

Comment: Can you check if the class implementing this interface com.example.repository.UserRepository check if its available on the classpath and if its annotated with @Repository annotation

Comment: update your question with application.properties

Comment: Post your controller code and repository here.

Comment: It's wired. I am clue less. Your code looks ok to me though.

Comment: do you have more output of your exception? And can you try to comment out `public User findOneByName(String name);` and just try to start the app again.

Comment: getting same error @Patrick

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages="com.example.repository")` at the `Start` class.

Comment: It will b placed on repository?

Comment: On startup class, as I mentioned. Start.class in your case

Comment: I got one more error like, org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'

Comment: For those using the swagger codegen tool which generates io.swagger.Swagger2SpringBoot. Yes adding your bits into '@ComponentScan' does not work. For some reason Spring 2.1.5 can't look outside io.swagger so this fix worked for me. '@Repository' also did not work. I'm talking MongoDb setup here guys.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of MongoRepository, I tried CrudRepository interface. Its working fine.