# com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data

I tried to create custom query using @Query annotation. But it throws some error.

This is my Repository

```
package com.springboot.springmongodb.user;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String>{
    @Override
    User findOne(String id);

    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    @Query("SELECT user FROM User user WHERE user.username = :username")
    public List<User> findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);

}
```

I want to create custom query for check username.

Here the error which I'm getting.

> 2017-12-04 14:46:10.413  WARN 1452 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method
>   'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'userRep'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
>   SELECT user FROM User user WHERE user.username = :username ^

Comment: can you show us the full exception?

Comment: It seems that you are declaring a SQL Query as mongodb. A mongo query should look like this: `@Query("{ 'firstname' : ?0 }")`

Comment: updated my full exception @YCF_L

Comment: Would you try to code format it? The line breaks are surely not original.

Comment: Yea I have mode changes for stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception tells that the `@Query` you gave gets treated as JSON. Taking a look at your imports leads us to the reason:

> ```
> import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
> ```

While your query `SELECT user FROM User user WHERE user.username = :username` would be valid for JPA (SQL), it's invalid for MongoDB. Either change your import to fit your database or change the query to fit it.

A valid mongoDB looks like from the [Spring Data MongoDB example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#d0e3309):

> ```
> public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String>
>
>   @Query("{ 'username' : ?0 }")
>   List<Person> findByThePersonsFirstname(String firstname);
>
> }
> ```

...And a valid JPA statement from the [Spring Data JPA example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query):

> ```
> public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
>
>   @Query("select u from User u where u.username = ?1")
>   User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
> }
> ```

This would need the import [`org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html)

Comment: Yes I have given the same import which you have mentioned.

Comment: That's the problem I think. What's your database?

Comment: Here am using Crudrepository interface

Comment: Absolutely mongodb

Comment: Than your query is invalid. Try change it as I suggested.

Comment: If am using MongoRepository Instead of CrudRepository it shows some error in previous.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525093/required-a-bean-of-type-that-could-not-be-found-spring-boot?noredirect=1#comment82008677_47525093

Comment: This is another problem. Your Repository has to be annotated as `@Repository` or at least `@Component` or be configured in a `@Configuration` class. While spring is magic it's not so magic that it instantiates a class out of nothing. Either this is missing or you didn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Oh btw. I didn't say you should change the Repository interface. I suggested to change your query.

Comment: yea I have changed my query its working. But inside my repository I haven't used any anotation like Repositor, Component and Configuration. Anyway thanks!

Comment: Does anyone here knows correct syntax to make this query work ???

@Query(value = "{ OID: ?0, Schema: { $not: /Something/ }  }"), when i execute this in Robo3T everything works, but when i add this in repository it does not work :(

Comment: If you have a question, please add a new question.